# linux sort inside a column

Tags: linux, sorting, field

I only want to sort a file by the second character in the second column by the number order.
the sample file like this:

```
aa 19
aa 189
aa 167
ab 13
nd 23
at 32
ca 90
```

I expect the result like

```
ca 90
at 32
ab 13
nd 23
aa 167
aa 189
aa 19
```

I use the command `sort -n -k 2.2,2.2 [filename]`.
But it shows me the result like this:

```
aa 167
aa 189
aa 19
ab 13
nd 23
at 32
ca 90
```

It is not the right answer. Does anybody know what's wrong with my command?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you didn't specify the correct column delimiter, and `sort` assumes it's a tab instead of a space.

```
sort -t ' ' -nk 2.2
```

works just fine.

Edit: in my `man` page it says that any whitespace is counted as delimiter by default, but the fact is that adding `-t ' '` solves it.

Comment: Thanks for editing and answer. But the weird thing is if i only sort the second column using sort -n -k 2. It seems to know the delimiter is space. The result is no problem. Do you know the reason?

Comment: @stevezhou I confirm this behavior, but I'm not sure why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -t ' ' -k2.2,2.2 filename
```